# How to avoid infinity rerender in React component that mutates a state that it depends on?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an API poller, that will fetch a list of users periodically. This query requires some pagination information, such as current page to fetch. Once the request is completed, the result will contain the new current page, which I need to store for the next request.

So, I tried something like:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

useInterval(
  () => {
    const res = await Service.getUsers(page);
    setUsers(res.items);
    setPage(res.page);
  },
  5000 // runs every 5 s
)

return [users, page, setPage]; // Set page is returned so it can be modified by user on pagination
```

The problem with the approach above is that the poller will update an internal state (page and users), which causes an infinity rerender.

I could use a useRef, but the idea would be to have this information stored in a global store (using Recoil or Zustand, e.g.), and consume the information from the store, so if e.g. the page is changed in the app, the poller will automatically use the latest information.

Even if I change the code above to use Recoil instead of useState, the problem remains, because mutating the value on recoil store will trigger a rerender to the component, which will run the poller again, update Recoil, run the poller again, so on and so forth.

Appreciate if someone have ideas on how to structure this code properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see is that you create a new interval every time you change the state

To fix this, use `useEffect` hook

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const int = useInterval(
    () => {
      const res = await Service.getUsers(page);
      setUsers(res.items);
      setPage(res.page);
    },
    5000 // runs every 5 s
  )
  return () => clearInteval(int)
}, [])

return [users, page, setPage];
```

Comment: I think I should have mentioned Recoil since the beginning, sorry.

If I replace useState by Recoill, the component will rerender over and over again, because setting the recoil state will trigger a rerender, since the component is subscribed for the changes itself made

Comment: I think better about the problem and looks like it's more about clarifying the problem than a technical challenge.

Will keep the question here for future reference.